# Performance overhead on WPF virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, .net-4.5

I have WPF app. There are few windows (each is working in its own thread) 5 - 10 windows. Each has only one significant control (which is data grid). Each data grid has 2000-3000 rows and 5 columns. Each row data bound to an item and when item's properties change the UI changes a lot (90% of the changes are - text, foreground, background). There are a 1000 changes per sec across all the windows.

If I switch virualization to Recycling the application consumes 35-40% less memory.

However I am guess that if the containers arent recycled the code must ran faster (since .NET wont need to re-bind containers and re-evaluate dep props and may be more).

Has anyone tried to investigate this in depth?

**Is there performance hit/advantage** in using containers recycling (**however small it is** I need to know).

**EDIT:** The items which get updates are 95% are visible (in other words if a row is invisible there is 99% chance it isnt going to be updated). Also grid rows content/number never change. Only text and colours change in the cells. The rows always stay the same.

Comment: `Thank you for adding information and not telling me that I dont need this` - **Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil**. I'm not saying you don't need this. I'm just saying that if your app runs just fine and there is no performance problem then there is nothing to optimize

Comment: very sorry here.. but i didnt ask to help me optimise my application.. i would never.. i know how busy you all are.. I am merely asking so I know.. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you use 1/3 less memory will probably result in a performance improvement in itself, due to better memory cache utilization and less garbage collection.

In addition, if a datagrid with over 2000 rows isn't virtualized, an update to any one of those rows needs to be propagated to the view. If it is virtualized, only rows that are visible on screen (and some buffer rows) need to be updated when changed.

Filling 2000 rows will take time. When virtualized, only a handful of rows need to be filled when data arrives, the other rows are filled when scrolling. If it isn't virtualized, less work needs to be done when scrolling, but more nees to be done when initializing.

But the real question is: is that extra work when scrolling visible? How many frames per second do you get when scrolling? Do you see slow UI updates? If not, virtualize.

It's a classic trade-off between memory usage and CPU usage, between fast initialization and somewhat slower scrolling on the one hand, and slow initialization and faster scrolling on the other.

Compare and measure, and see what works best for you.

Comment: If I could I would. There is no trade off because I have enough memory but only 8 cores of CPU. The items which get updates are 95% are visible so the argument on the updates of the grid outside visible area isnt valid in my case. Also grid rows content/number never change. Only text and colours change in the cells. the rows always stay the same

Comment: P.S. there is also not much of garbage collection is going.. the app is pretty much static in memory...

Comment: I agree with Kris. dp reevaluation is only one side of the equation. Standard mode will put more pressure on GC and cause heap fragmentation overtime.

Comment: could you guys explain why no recycling puts more pressure on GC?

Comment: The 'no-recycling' as you call it does not put pressure on the GC, but the data binding often does. Think about it: if one of the values you are displaying is not a string (e.g. an int), it needs to be converted to a string for display. When it changes, the old string is food for the garbage collector. No binding => no strings => no garbage to collect.

Comment: Kris. in my first reply : `The items which get updates are 95% are visible`.. so in other words - 95% of updates happen in only visible containers (so recycling or not recycling will not change anything GC wise)..

Comment: You asked how it can put pressure on the garbage collector and I told you. I'm not trying to sell you virtualization. Read my answer, I said "Compare and measure, and see what works best for you." It sounds like you did, and determined that no virtualization works best for you. You have more information about the problem than I have, but even with the information you gave us, I would say you are probably correct. It seems you assume I disagree with you, but I don't.